# How can Gremlin script be executed for an embedded Neo4j database?

Tags: java, neo4j, gremlin

I have an embedded Neo4j database and am using the fluent API to run Gremlin traversals against it. I have a requirement to be able to execute Gremlin script (not Cypher) against this database. However since access to an embedded Neo4j database does not happen via a Cluster instance, I do not know how to get a handle to a Client object which has the necessary methods to execute Gremlin script... e.g. `client.sumbit(query)`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're saying that you want to process Gremlin strings in your code against Neo4j. You can use the `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine` directly. Here's a simple example using TinkerGraph, rather than Neo4j (obviously, you can easily swap in Neo4j and this code will work in the same way):

```
gremlin> bindings = new javax.script.SimpleBindings()
gremlin> bindings.put('g', TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal())
gremlin> engine = new org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine()
==>org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine@7b676112
gremlin> results = engine.eval("g.V(1)", bindings).toList()
==>v[1]
```

TinkerPop also has a more advanced [GremlinExecutor](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/debd56137299571bc97d51a0183cb1edf309c722/gremlin-groovy/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/groovy/engine/GremlinExecutor.java) which wraps the `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine` and provides some additional features that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This seems to work fine for queries. But for add/updates, it doesn't. If I try passing in the following statement: `g.addV('Person2').property('name', 'Jill').next()` I receive the following: `"org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to load NODE with id 846."` Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: I'm not sure how you've structured things, but I'd guess the problem is related to transactions. in what context are you getting that error? from the `eval()` call? are multiple threads involved? perhaps you need to `g.tx().commit()` your transaction somewhere?